# I'd like to return all the vertex and all the path for the vertexes which we returned

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

My question is that I want to return all the vertexes. And get all paths between all returned vertexes.

For example I will get all the tags which is person. And I also want to get all the paths between the vertexes.

vertexes : g.V().has('tag','person')
How can we get the net path?

Comment: def graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("POC");
def g=graph.traversal();
g.V().repeat(
  bothE().dedup().store('edges').bothV().dedup().store('vertices')
).times(1).cap('vertices', 'edges')
This is show 1 degree net.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g.V().has('tag', 'person')` is not going to return any paths, since this query is meant to only return a list of vertices.

I'll assume from your comment that you want all paths between all such vertices, then the following query should be useful:

```
g.V().has('tag', 'person').bothE().otherV().path()
```

It might be useful to add a `dedup()` step on destination vertices, so you don't get duplicate paths:

```
g.V().has('tag', 'person').bothE().otherV().dedup().path()
```

For a more sophisticated output of `path()`, you can experiment with the Gremlin console and the toy graph. The following apply different `by()` modulators for source vertex, traversed edge, and destination vertex (respectively):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().bothE().otherV().dedup().path().by(id).by(label).by(id)
==>[1, created, 3]
==>[1, knows, 2]
==>[1, knows, 4]
==>[2, knows, 1]
==>[3, created, 6]
==>[4, created, 5]
```

Reference:

- http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/reference/#path-step